# Eclipse Android Protocol isn't supported

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I am developing a webview app with android and I have a link which when clicked a call is made. Currently I have the following:

```
if (tablet == false) {  
    html += '<a rel="external" href="tel:21212121">';
}
else {
    html += '<a rel="external" href="facetime:\\21212121">';
}
```

From the code above I am checking if the device is a tablet or not. If it is a normal mobile I use the tel link if it is a table I use facetime. Now I know that facetime is used only on IoS so I can change it to skype etc.

What I would like to is to prevent the Message "Protocol isn't supported" from showing.

Thanks

Comment: You can catch the thrown exception, if any.

Comment: From the javascript side? As this happens when clicked.